# Form action not directing me to the approriate page

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have the following form:

```
<form action="/payment" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
                <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-2">
                <input />
</form


 <button className="w-full bg-purple-500 py-3 text-center text-white">
                    Register Now
                  </button>
```

When I click the submit button, I'm not being directed to the payment path.
This is what I have in the onSubmitForm function

```
  async function onSubmitForm(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    try {


      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/user", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      } )
      
      console.log("res: ", response.body)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("EROR: ", error.message)
    }
  }
```

I know there are other ways in which I change the path, but I'm trying to figure out why the action is not working in this context.

Comment: The action is not working due to the "e.preventDefault()".

Comment: Just to make clear, the `action` is what page will be sent the POST request…not where you will end up after submitting. If you want to navigate to a new page after submit, you will need to listen to the response, and if success, navigate to other page via `window.location` or similar.

Comment: Also, the button should be inside the form in order for it to trigger the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the setup that might work for you:

```
export default function App() {
  async function onSubmitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/user", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify("data")
      });

      console.log("res: ", response.body);
      window.location.replace("/payment");
      // You might also want to check `location.assign`
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("EROR: ", error.message);
    }
  }

  return (
    {/* No need for action, as the onSubmitForm fetch is taking care of POST-ing the data */}
    <form onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
      <input />
      <button>Register Now</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Depending on the setup of your application, you might want to consider using a routing library like [React Router](https://reactrouter.com) and using the [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) or [redirect](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect) to redirect the application to another dynamic route.